# How do I create a multidimensional array from an array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I need to create a multidimensional array from an array.

For example, let's say the initial array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

I need a multidimensional array of

> [ [1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,6] ]

I feel like this should be so easy, but I am stuck.

Here's what I have so far, which is wrong

```
def solution(a)
  empty =[]
  a.each do |x|
    new_array = Array(x)
    empty.push(new_array)   
  end
  empty.reverse
end
```

and I've tried

```
def solution(a)
  empty =[]
  for i in 1..a.size
    new_array = Array(a.pop)
    empty.push(new_array)   
  end
  empty.reverse
end
```

Anybody have a solution or suggestion?

**EDIT: I realized that I never specified whether the array will consist of more than integers. For my purposes, I am looking for a solution that will accommodate integers or strings.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `flatten`:

```rb
arr = []
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6].map{ |elm| arr = [arr, elm].flatten }
arr # => [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to generate lists of sequential numbers, use [`1.upto(6)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-upto) to iterate 6 times, then make the individual arrays by mapping with `1.upto(i)`.

```
1.upto(6).map { |i| 1.upto(i) }
```

This makes an Enumerator of Enumerators. These should be fine, and you'll save memory if they get large. If you want to force them to be Arrays, add `to_a`.

```
1.upto(6).map { |i| 1.upto(i).to_a }
```

If you want a more generic solution, use [Cary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61923232/14660).

Comment: Despite the question stating, "*let's say* the initial array = `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`" your solution is unrelated to the value of `array`; it's just a shorthand way of writing the literal `[[1[, [1,2],...]`. I assume `array` could be `[1,2,3,4,5]` or `['cat', 7, :dog, 3.1]`, and if it were the latter, the OP would want  `[["cat"], ["cat", 7], ["cat", 7, :dog], ["cat", 7, :dog, 3.1]]`. Other answers interpreted the question similarly. David, please clarify: is the specific array `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` the only one of interest or do you want the array to be arbitrary in size and content, or something else?

Comment: @CarySwoveland [I took that to be part of the solution, not the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If so, replace `1.upto(6)` with the initial array.

Comment: Let's see what David says.

Comment: Ah this is a good point. For my purposes, I will actually be dealing with non-integers. I just used integers since it was the simplest way to write my question down. I replaced 1.upto(6) with the original array, but I am realizing I should mark another answer as the solution. So sorry about the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

arr.size.times.map { |i| arr[0..i] }
  #=> [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  #    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not quite accurate so in more general way:

```
def multidemensional(ary)
  ary.map { |x| 1.upto(x).to_a }
end
```

```
multidemensional([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
# => [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

multidemensional([2, 2, 3, 7])
# => [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```